# Add Custom function to Auth Class Laravel (Extends Guard Class)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I had modified a vendor file of Laravel placed at

*/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php*

but it will be overwritten upon updating Laravel.

I'm looking for a way to put the code somewhere in my /app to prevent the overwrite.

The function modified is

```
public function UpdateSession() {
    $this->session->set('type', $type); //==> Set Client Type
}
```

Also there's a new function on the file:

```
public function type() {
    return $this->session->get('type'); //==> Get Client Type
}
```

Codes above are called in many places in my application.

Any idea?

Comment: If you want to override a method you should create a class that extends the Guard class and *then* override the method, and use that class throughout your app. You shouldn't be messing with Laravel source code directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps:
1- create myGuard.php

```
class myGuard extends Guard
{
    public function login(Authenticatable $user, $remember = false)
    {
        $this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier(), $user->type);
        if ($remember) {
            $this->createRememberTokenIfDoesntExist($user);
            $this->queueRecallerCookie($user);
        }
        $this->fireLoginEvent($user, $remember);
        $this->setUser($user);
    }

    protected function updateSession($id, $type = null)
    {
        $this->session->set($this->getName(), $id);
        $this->session->set('type', $type);
        $this->session->migrate(true);
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->session->get('type');
    }
}
```

2- in AppServiceProvider or new service provider or routes.php:

```
public function boot()
{
    Auth::extend(
        'customAuth',
        function ($app) {
            $model = $app['config']['auth.model'];
            $provider = new EloquentUserProvider($app['hash'],    $model);
            return new myGuard($provider, App::make('session.store'));
        }
    );
}
```

3- in config/auth.php

```
'driver' => 'customAuth',
```

4- now you can use this

```
Auth::type();
```

Comment: how should MyGuard by included ? I have it an "Extensions" folder. But with "/use App\Extensions\MyGuard;" in AppServiceProvider it is not found.

In the MyGuard file, I have "use Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;" but I am also not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like you need to update the Guard at all. As far as I can see you are only trying to retrieve data from the session. And that's definitely no business for the Guard itself.

You have multiple ways of accessing the session yourself:

```
// via Session-Facade
$type = Session::get('type');
Session::put('type', $type);

// via Laravels helper function
$type = session('type'); // get
session()->put('type', $type); // set
session(['type' => $type']); // alternative
```